# cpan install module DBD::mysql fails, snow leopard

Tags: perl, osx-snow-leopard, cpan

I am installing dependancies for Koha. This is requiring perl and cpan usage, of which this is my first time. I installed mysql via the hivelogic instructions. I am running 10.6.2 on a 32bit mac mini.

Here is the terminal output:

```
John-Breedloves-Mac-mini:~ john_breedlove$ sudo -H cpan -i DBD::mysql
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.19)
Going to read /var/root/.cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Tue, 19 Jan 2010 14:52:55 GMT
Running install for module 'DBD::mysql'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.71)
Running make for C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.013.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.48)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9715)
  LWP not available

Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get
    http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /var/root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.013.tar.gz ok
x DBD-mysql-4.013/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/DBD/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/DBD/mysql/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/Bundle/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/Bundle/DBD/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
x DBD-mysql-4.013/mysql.xs
x DBD-mysql-4.013/dbdimp.c
x DBD-mysql-4.013/myld
x DBD-mysql-4.013/INSTALL.html
x DBD-mysql-4.013/Makefile.PL.embedded
x DBD-mysql-4.013/TODO
x DBD-mysql-4.013/README
x DBD-mysql-4.013/MANIFEST.SKIP
x DBD-mysql-4.013/ChangeLog
x DBD-mysql-4.013/Makefile.PL
x DBD-mysql-4.013/META.yml
x DBD-mysql-4.013/dbdimp.h
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/prepare_memory_usage.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/proc_example2b.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/proc_example2.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/decimal_test.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/bug30033pg.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/proc_example2a.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/proc_example4.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/bug21028.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/bug14979.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/bug30033.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/issue21946.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/proc_example3.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/eg/proc_example1.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/constants.h
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/85init_command.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40listfields.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40bindparam.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/mysql.mtest
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/41bindparam.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/76multi_statement.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40nulls.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/32insert_error.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40catalog.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/51bind_type_guessing.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40bindparam2.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/41blobs_prepare.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/20createdrop.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/70takeimp.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/42bindparam.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/00base.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/55utf8.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/65types.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40server_prepare_error.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/31insertid.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/29warnings.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40types.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/10connect.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/lib.pl
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/mysql.dbtest
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/35limit.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/71impdata.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40blobs.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40server_prepare.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40numrows.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/35prepare.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/40keyinfo.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/75supported_sql.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/60leaks.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/50commit.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/30insertfetch.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/50chopblanks.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/25lockunlock.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/t/80procs.t
x DBD-mysql-4.013/MANIFEST
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.20)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.013.tar.gz

Can't locate DBI/DBD.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.9 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9/darwin-2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.8.9 .) at Makefile.PL line 24.
Warning: No success on command[/opt/local/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.013.tar.gz
  /opt/local/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/98822/mac-os-x-10-6-2-install-dbdmysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clue was in this line of your quoted output:

```
    Can't locate DBI/DBD.pm in @INC...
```

You'll be seeing this type of error a lot as you develop in Perl! It means that you are missing a module dependency, generally because the module hasn't been installed from CPAN.

Therefore, you need to install [DBI::DBD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI::DBD) first before [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::mysql). There are [some complicated reasons](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI::DBD#Pure_Perl_version_of_Makefile.PL) why this isn't installed automatically by `cpan` as a prerequisite (usually when installing a module or distribution, it will automatically install all its dependencies):

> PREREQ_PM tells MakeMaker that DBI (version 1.03 in this case) is required for this module. This will issue a warning that DBI 1.03 is missing if someone attempts to install your DBD without DBI 1.03. See CONFIGURE below for why this does not work reliably in stopping cpan testers failing your module if DBI is not installed.
>
> CONFIGURE is a subroutine called by MakeMaker during WriteMakefile. By putting the require DBI::DBD in this section we can attempt to load DBI::DBD but if it is missing we exit with success. As we exit successfully without creating a Makefile when DBI::DBD is missing cpan testers will not report a failure. This may seem at odds with PREREQ_PM but PREREQ_PM does not cause WriteMakefile to fail (unless you also specify PREREQ_FATAL which is strongly discouraged by MakeMaker) so WriteMakefile would continue to call dbd_dbi_arch_dir and fail.

You can install both modules at once with:

```
    sudo -H cpan DBI::DBD DBD::mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

I spent a most of an evening googleing and trying the various directions to get DBD::mysql to work with my existing osx perl installation. I was making no progress and finally tried installing active perl. It comes with a perl package manager (ppm). From there, you can install a pure perl mysql driver (DBD::mysqlPP) and this bypasses all the compilation headaches. - Just be sure to change your code to use DBD::mysqlPP rather than DBD::mysql - in my case, I changed 
this:
my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:schemaName:localhost';

to this:
my $dsn = 'DBI:mysqlPP:schemaName:localhost';

Answer (score 0):

Try installing DBI.pm first.